# Оптимальная схема БД ClickHouse для интернет магазина

Tags: база-данных, clickhouse

Доброго времени суток.

Решил использовать ClickHouse для аналитики. Регистрирую примерно 30 000 000 событий в месяц. У меня есть несколько разных типов событий, у всех у них часть атрибутов совпадает, поэтому решил делать одну главную таблицу и на каждый тип события свою дополнительную с уникальным набором колонок. Но JOIN оказались непосильными.

Сейчас думаю над двумя схемами

- одна большая таблица в которой будут ВСЕ колонки ВСЕХ типов событий
- на каждый тип события будет своя таблица с полным набором колонок

Например

- событие "посетил страницу" имеет колонки: дата посещения, URL, REFER, ID пользователя, ID сессии
- событие "положил в корзину" имеет колонки: дата и время, ID товара, количество товара, URL страницы, ID пользователя, ID сессии
- событие "удалил товар из корзины" имеет колонки: дата и время, ID товара, URL страницы, ID пользователя, ID сессии

Что лучше выбрать, может посоветуете?

Comment: Вам нужно отталкиваться от необходимой аналитики. Если вам нужна общая аналитика и внезапные ad-hoc запросы "сколько событий с корзиной совершает пользователей", то общий поток, потому что детализировать просто не получится. Если вы четко знаете, что вам нужно вести потоварную аналитику, то под это дело заводится отдельная таблица, но общий поток при этом стоит на всякий оставить.

Comment: Если что, есть тематический телеграм-чат, в т.ч. непосредственно с разработчиками и early adopters - https://telegram.me/clickhouse_ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Письмо из Яндекса

Добрый день.

По нашему опыту, лучше всего подходит вариант - одна широкая таблица со столбцами для всех видов событий.
Разреженность таблицы не составляет проблемы - объём данных на диске и эффективность работы от этого не страдает.

Выполнение запросов, использующих разные виды событий (пример: вычисление конверсии посещений в корзину) серьёзно упрощается
- JOIN делать не нужно, достаточно GROUP BY с агрегатными функциями с условиями, вида sumIf(..., event_type = 1).

Разные таблицы имеет смысл делать в случае, если в таблицах разные ключи.
Также, если одна из таблиц существенно меньше, чем остальные, но запросы к ней идут чаще, и для них важна более высокая скорость, то можно выделить такие события в отдельную таблицу. При этом, можно записывать эти события и в одну, "объединённую" таблицу тоже.